# I cannot add record to database asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I have a problem, I would like to add some records to database but when I'm clicking on submit button, nothing done.

Some functions for submit button:

```
protected void rezerwujButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rezerwacje nowaRezerwacja = new rezerwacje();

        nowaRezerwacja.imie_klienta = imieTextBox.Text;
        nowaRezerwacja.nazwisko_klienta = nazwiskoTextBox.Text;
        nowaRezerwacja.email_klienta = emailTextBox.Text;
        nowaRezerwacja.nrtel_klienta = telefonKomorkowyTextBox.Text;

        bazaDC.rezerwacjes.InsertOnSubmit(nowaRezerwacja);
        bazaDC.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

Some forms in html:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Rezerwacja">
      <asp:Panel ID="panel3" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="imieTextBox" runat="server" placeholder="Imię"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="nazwiskoTextBox" runat="server" placeholder="Nazwisko"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="emailTextBox" runat="server" TextMode="Email" placeholder="Email"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="telefonKomorkowyTextBox" runat="server" TextMode="Phone" placeholder="Telefon kom."></asp:TextBox>
        <div id="plansza"></div>
        <asp:Button ID="rezerwujButton" runat="server" Text="Zarezerwuj" OnClick="rezerwujButton_Click" />

        </asp:Panel>
```

In this form there is a popup window.
I can't understand because before I have code in many forms and everything was alright but now unfortunately no... What's wrong with that code?
I'll add some jquery code, that open the window form:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
          effect: "puff",
          duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
          effect: "explode",
          duration: 1000
      }
  });

  $( ".opener" ).on( "click", function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
  });
});
```

Comment: There could be many causes. Better start looking from the setup of connection string, data access layer, and then the client side coding.

Comment: Yes, but all other operations on database Im doing on the same connection string and everything else working but just this one  form on popup window don't want to work

Comment: There should be a message if it's an error on `bazaDC.SubmitChanges();`. Got anything from that?

Comment: unfortunately not, I think, that is something wrong with JavaScript or something bucause when I want to click submit button, It looks like not clickable... I no have idea what is wrong with that form, I have to do it on blank project...

Comment: I tried do it without the popup window and It is working, so now there is a question, why is that no working with a popup windows?

Comment: Is the same code base resided in the popup page? Or you're accessing the code behind from parent page.

Comment: Popup window is just div dialog, I added that code in question and I include that code to site.master in header.

Comment: `<div>` shouldn't modify the behaviour of click action. Is there anything you've particularly done on `rezerwujButton`. How is it different from the one outside `<div>`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/dasnJqp9 There is whole file.

Answer (score 0):

Try also using `onclient` click on your existing button.

```
<asp:Button ID="rezerwujButton" runat="server" Text="Zarezerwuj" OnClientClick="clientClick();" />
```

Then create a hidden button with the `rezerwujButton_Click` function you've already built.

```
<asp:Button id="hidButton" runat="server" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;" onclick="rezerwujButton_Click" />
```

Create the following javascript function to trigger the post back on the hidden button.

```
function clientClick(){
    __doPostBack('<%#hidButton.UniqueId %>');
}
```

Comment: Nothing, not working :( I can't understand why I can't send form on popup windows generated by javascript?

Comment: You mentioned the function call works when there's no popup, can you also provide the code? To me it's like a problem of the bonding between frontend and code behind, would be good to have your working version to confirm.

Comment: Sure I can provide code but I just change the id which responsible for the container for popup, you know... Do you mean my version Visual Studio? That is Visual Studio 2015 Community edition.